# Git: How to revert everything but current working head on to a previous commit

Tags: git

In git I already ran `git add -u && git commit -a --amend` to my working changes. I did not push the new commit to origin. I now found some previous git revision broke the build.

I want to keep my new commit, but go back to the last known 'good' git revision: say `04c06eb2acf154ba0e7f4e27044d1dffa6a42473`.

I could run `git reset --hard 04c06eb2acf154ba0e7f4e27044d1dffa6a42473` but that would lose my current revision

I also can't use `git rebase -i HEAD~100` because the last good branch was a long time ago.

What is the best way to achieved my desired result?

Comment: just a guess: consider git checkout <last-good-commit> ; git cherry-pick <new-commit>

Comment: Thanks @LynHeadley.  But to clarify, I didn't actually push my new commit.  So I don't think it can be cherry-picked.

Comment: Do you mean that you have pushed all previous commits to origin except the new commit?

Comment: @pktangyue yes, I did not use git push.  I'll update question to reflect.

Comment: But I don't know why it can't be cherry-picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just "back up" your last commit with

```
git format-patch -1
```

then undo what "broke" the build. After this you might need to manually apply the patch file, but you won't have lost anything.

Comment: Awesome, that worked great.  Note to others, use git am to apply the resulting patch.